# How to validate data to ensure only allowed strings are uploaded in DB using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am building an upload feature to import client data into MySQL database in a codeigniter application. In order to open, read and process data from excel to MySQL database, I am using PHPExcel Library.

One of the requirement for upload is that script should only allow certain values in columns read by PHPExcel. If any non allowed value is provided than script should reject that row.

For Example: I have an attribute named as panStatus (Column in Client Table). I need to make sure that the uploaded excel file contain only either of the two possible values for panStatus i.e. 'Company' or 'Non Company'. Anything else should not be inserted into table.

I have came up with following code but i am sure there will be better ways to do same.

```
public function client_bulk_do_insert()
    {
        $result = $this->client_model->get_list_of_client_uploaded_files();
        if($result)
        {
            $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
            foreach ($result->result_array() as $row) {
                $file_id = $row['id'];
                $file_name = CLIENT_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH.$row['file_name'];
                $data = excelToArray($file_name);
                foreach ($data as $key => $actualArray) {
                    //perform validations
                    if(company_check($actualArray['nameClient']))
                    {
                        $error[] = 'Invalid Client Name or Client Already Present';
                    }

                    $pan_status = array('Company','Non Company');
                    $youtube_verified = array('No','Yes');
                    $client_status = array('NA','Partnership', 'Prop','Private Limited','Individual');
if(!array_search($actualArray['panStatus'],$pan_status))
                    {
                        $error[] = 'Invalid Pan Status Value';
                    }

                    if(!array_search($actualArray['youtubeVerified'],$youtube_verified))
                    {
                        $error[] = 'Invalid Youtube Verified Value';
                    }

                    if(!array_search($actualArray['clientStatus'],$client_status))
                    {
                        $error[] = 'Invalid Client Status Value';
                    }

                    $result = $this->client_model->create_new_client($data);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Please note in actual I have to do such validations on 22 columns of uploaded sheet with at least 1500 rows input. Is there any inbuilt support in PHPExcel to do such validations ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if there are 22 checks and 1500 rows, the total number of validity checks would be 22*1500, there's no way around that.